# Uploaded file is not a valid X.509 Certificate, or the password is invalid

Tags: azure

I am working on an Azure project. To secure this site, I wanted to install a SSL certificate. So when I uploaded .pfx file, I am getting error message **"Uploaded file is not a valid X.509 Certificate, or the password is invalid. "** when I try to upload a certificate. I was able to do the same without any issue last week. Kindly share the steps to fix if you have faced similar issue.

Thanks

Comment: I'm sorry to hear of your troubles. Do you have a question?

Comment: Sorry, I have updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Friends, I got the solution from msdn forum and here is the solution.

```
$apiCert = get-item cert:\CurrentUser\MY\XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
$subscription_id = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"

Add-Certificate -SubscriptionId $subscription_id  -serviceName <servicename> -CertificateToDeploy .\<servicename>.cloudapp.net.pfx -password xyz -certificate $apiCert
```

You will have to save this as a powershell script (.ps1) and run it in power shell. You will have to install the azure add on in powershell from http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/azurecmdlets/Wiki/View.aspx?title=Sample%20Scripts&referringTitle=Home

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems trying to load a replacement self-signed certificate pfx file (used for Identity Server 4 token generation) to a Web App on Azure.  The error message returned on the Azure portal was `The password is incorrect, or the certificate is not valid`.

After a lot of investigation, I found that it was due to me using OpenSSL v3 to create the new certificate, rather than v1 that I'd used previously.  (I was using the OpenSSL builds from [Shining Light Productions](https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html).)

This created the X509 certificate serial number as a 20 byte (40 character hex string) value, whereas OpenSSL v1 created it with an 8 byte (16 character hex string) value.

The Azure upload on the TLS/SSL Settings page for the web app rejected the 20 byte version, but uploaded the 8 byte version.

I don't know if the fact that you can seemingly perform the same action succesfully as a powershell/Azure cli command seems to indicate some issue with the Azure upload certificate validation code?

The [X509 Specification](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5280#section-4.1.2.2) states that the serial number must be no more than 20 bytes, so the one generated by OpenSSL v3 is a valid one.